# Añadiendo datos en DataBase Firebase en android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase

Buen dia,
Requiero agregar varias dosis que tengo guardadas en (String) pero implementando el ejemplo que encontre de Firebase me reemplaza el dato no lo guarda

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference my = database.getReference("dosis");



my.setValue(""+Micalculo);
```

Realizando esto, no se si deba y como usar de forma sencilla el evento onChildAdded

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para añadir varios datos bajo un mismo nodo, utiliza el metodo `push()` antes de `setValue()`

por ejemplo, modifica esto de tu codigo

```
my.setValue(""+Micalculo);
```

por

```
my.push().setValue(""+Micalculo);
```

Por ejemplo para crear keys personalizadas podes hacer lo siguiente

```
my.child("lo_que_quieras_poner").setValue(""+Micalculo);
```

por ejemplo podes definir un for e ir poniendo keys mediante vas agregando elementos

```
int n = cantidad_de_elementos;
for(int i = 0 ; i<n ; i++){
   my.child(i).setValue(""+Micalculo);
}
```

por ejemplo tambien para darle el nombre que quieras vos a la key a partir de un `EditText.` Cuando ingresamos texto podemos declarar la llave que va a contener que el valor de `setValue()`

```
EditText et = findViewById(R.id.eText);
String key = et.getText().toString();
//Aca recomendaria hacer un dataSnapshot preguntando con un contains si no hay ya un child con el mismo valor para que no se pise.
my.child(key).setValue(""+Micalculo);
```

Y asi podes ir jugando con muchos valores random o los que quieras poner antes de tu `setValue()` , se lo pasas a un child

Esto generara una clave unica para cada valor que pases en setValue()

Comment: Muchas gracias Amigo, me sirvio, Sabes como puedo cambiar este nombre -LNDHOKND5KuDrzTJq-2:"50" al dato cuando se añade las letras como estandar aleatorias

Comment: te referis a cambiar el valor aleatorio que figura?

Comment: Asi es , es posible ?

Comment: ahi edite la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!